# 'cannot import name views' when doing a migration (Django, Python 3.6)

Tags: django, python-3.x

so I am doing a little project for a class with **pythonanywhere.com**
I am following the instructions given by the teacher, and I entered the following command in the virtualenv console:

```
python .../manage.py makemigrations
```

But I have this error message :

```
'cannot import name views'.
```

I also had similar error (such as `cannot import path`, etc...), but I was able to fix them searching on this website. Unfortunately, I didn't find any solution that worked for this particular problem.

So I'd like help to solve it. And I am also wondering if so many issues while trying to make a migration is normal ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Here is the urls.py file that seem to be the problem,

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    url('user', views.user.list, name='users-list'),
    url('<user_id>', views.user.profile, name='user-profile'),
    url('listing', views.listing.list, name='listings-list'),
    url('<listing_id>', views.listing.profile, name='listing-profile'),
    url('currency', views.currency.list, name='currencies-list'),
    url('<currency_id>', views.currency.profile, name='currency-profile'),
]
```

And Here is the full stuff from the virtualenv console.

```
(django2) 16:28 ~ $ python /home/infosgr37a/project/manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/infosgr37a/project/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/infosgr37a/project/mysite/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    url('', include('solvaycoin.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/infosgr37a/project/solvaycoin/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: cannot import name views
```

Full layout :

```
-Project/
---mysite/
---solvaycoin/
------migrations/
------static/
------templates/
------views/
------__init__.py
------__init__.pyc
------admin.py
------admin.pyc
------apps.py
------apps.pyc
------models.py
------models.pyc
------urls.py
------urls.pyc
---manage.py
```

So 'views' is a folder.
I hope this is clear enough, I didn't know how to do it properly.

Edit:
Tried what Babu recommended, and it got me post the 'view' problem.
But now I have another one:

```
    (django2) 18:51 ~ $ python /home/infosgr37a/project/manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/infosgr37a/project/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/infosgr37a/project/mysite/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
url('', include('solvaycoin.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/home/infosgr37a/project/solvaycoin/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
url('user', views.user.list, name='users-list'),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Is it because I moved my views to a single file ?

Comment: Post your urls.py file.

Comment: Try to pass the full name instead of using the . as a relative path. Instead of 'from . import views' try doing 'import solvaycoin.views' or try 'from solvaycoin.views import *'.  The relative path might be looking in the wrong place if your layout is borked.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added it.

Comment: I tried 'import solvaycoin.views' and  'from solvaycoin.views import *' and it still doesn't work 'no module name views' .

Comment: And I tried 'python manage.py makemigrations' but the console tells me 'can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Answer (score 1):

There is no views.py in your `solvaycoin` application folder. Create views.py in your `solvaycoin` folder Paste your functions and class ('homepage', user.list, user.profile, listing.list, listing.profile, currency.list, currency.profile) inside that view.py file. Hope It Works.............!!!!!!!

Comment: There should also be a tests.py file. Looks like a couple things are missing. Not sure if this is OP issue or if PythonAnywhere is the issue.

Comment: "views.user.list" where you are maintaining this user.list function.